# Как сделать, чтобы background-position-y: bottom; у body не поднимался при появлении клавиатуры на телефонах?

Tags: javascript, css

Я задал для body стиль background-position: bottom center, но когда на телефонах открывается клавиатура, фон смещается вверх. Как сделать, чтобы не смещался?

Comment: Выложи код, так быстрее помогут, а гадать, что, почему, да как, можно вечно...

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, проблема решится так:

```
body {
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: top;
    background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
    background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Я пробовал без background-size: cover; - не работает. С cover не подходит мне.